# Возврат результата из потока через pthread_join(): не могу вернуть результат

Tags: c, многопоточность, pthread

Я учусь работать с потоками в C.

Фактически, при этом вызывается две функции:
pthread_create() и pthread_join().
И происходит вызов кода, который описан в так называемой "поточной функции". Пример я приведу чуть ниже.

С передачей аргументов внутрь функциии - нет проблем, я создаю структуру, всё туда кладу, преобразовываю струтуру к (void *), а внутри поточной функции выполняю обратное преобразование.

А вот вернуть результат из поточной функции - не получается.

Я убил на это море времени.

Я прочиал все ссылки по запросу "c pthread_join return value example" и посмотрел [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ln3el6PR__Q&ab_channel=CodeVault) с утьюба.

Понятнее не стало. Моя проблема, как я её вижу, вот в чем:

У меня в pthread_join() возвращается адрес, по которому лежит результат.

Но этот адрес - это указатель типа void *. И я не могу этот адрес преобразовать обартно к типу, который я ожидаю вернуть из функции. То есть, я не могу `void *` преобразовывать к произвольному типу: меня компилятор бъет по рукам.

Нет ли какого то способа, достаточно общего, чтобы я мог вернуть из "поточной функции" не только int (это единственный пример, который работает), но и другой тип? Идеально было бы тоже возвращать структуру, в котрую я могу положить уже что угодно.

Второй способ, который мне приходит в голову - это возвращать результат через ту же структуру, которая передаётся в качестве аргумента (то есть, предусмотреть в ней поля для возврата результата). Но, прежде чем идти этим путём, я бы хотел получить от Вас совет.

Спасибо заранее!

Теперь - код, в котором первый пример работает, а второй (который отличается тем, что я "механически" поменял тип int на тип float - уже не работает)

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct thread_args{
        int x;int y;
    };

    void* func_int_from_thread(void *arg){
        struct thread_args *par;
        par = (struct thread_args*) arg;
        int* res = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *res = 150;
        return (void*)res;
    };

    void* func_float_from_thread(void *arg){
        struct thread_args *par;
        par = (struct thread_args*) arg;
        float* res = malloc(sizeof(float));
        *res = 147.4;
        return (void*)res;
    };


    int main(){

        struct thread_args targs = { .x=10, .y=25 };
        
        // Шаг 0 - возвращаем целое число
        int* res_int; // это указатель на целое число. То есть указатель на то место в памяти, где будет лежать результат
        pthread_t pid0;
        pthread_create ( &pid0, NULL, func_int_from_thread, (void*)&targs );
        pthread_join ( pid0, (void**)&res_int );
        int tmp = *res_int;
        printf ( "Integer result: %d \n", tmp );
        // результат возвращается нормально. Отметим следующие особеннсти:
        // 1) выделение памяти происходит внутри "поточной функции" func_int_from_thread
        // 2) возвращается из "поточной функции" всегда указатель
     
        // Шаг 1 - возвращаем float
        // Напишем вторую "поточную функцию", которая возвращает float
        float* res_float; // это указатель на float - число. То есть указатель на то место в памяти, где будет лежать результат
        pthread_t pid1;
        pthread_create ( &pid1, NULL, func_float_from_thread, (void*)&targs );
        pthread_join ( pid1, (void**)&res_float );
        float tmp2 = *res_float;
        printf ( "Float result: %d \n", tmp2 );
    }
```

Comment: Вы как минимум неправильно печатаете результат. Для float нужно использовать спецификатор форматирования `%f`. С ним у меня работает. Хотя и дока  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html по `pthread_join` говорит, что результат берется из `pthread_exit`, которого у вас нет (как минимум явного).

Comment: Спасибо. Да, со спецификатором формата я прокололся - с C++ быстро привыкаешь к тому, что не надо думать, как там напечатать... я посмотрел - и мне показалось, что pthread_exit используется в случае, если мне нужно прервать выполнение потока. я не видел в примерах, что pthread_exit вызывается явно. Сейчас еще попробую...

Comment: `man pthread_create` проясняет картину с возвращаемым значением. `return` из функции эквивалентен `pthread_exit`.

Answer (score 1):

Большое спасибо всем за подсказки.

В общем, моей первоначальной целью было - научиться возвращать массивы из pthread_join().

Массивы я так и не научился возвращать: всегда наталкивался на segmantation fault.

Я не смог сделать этого иначе, чем "обернув" массив в структуру.

Когда есть структура - то она как то "изолирует" меня от этого бесконечноко кол-ва "звездочек", которые надо дописать, чтобы преобразовать тип "туда и обратно".

У меня получился такой вот работающий пример. Надеюсь, он еще кому нибудь поможет.

```
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    struct thread_args{
        int x;int y;
        float f;
    };

    struct thread_rez{
        float rez;
        int* arr;
    };

    void* func_int_from_thread(void *arg){
        struct thread_args *par;
        par = (struct thread_args*) arg;
        int* res = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *res = 150;
        return (void*)res;
    };

    void* func_float_from_thread(void *arg){
        struct thread_args *par;
        par = (struct thread_args*) arg;
        float* res = malloc(sizeof(float));
        *res = 147.4;
        return (void*)res;
    };

    void* func_struct_from_thread(void *arg){
        struct thread_args *par;
        par = (struct thread_args*) arg;
        struct thread_rez* trez = malloc(sizeof(trez));
        trez->arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
        trez->rez=120.2;
        trez->arr[0] = 1; trez->arr[1] = 2; trez->arr[2] = 3;
        return (void*)trez;
    };

    int main(){

        struct thread_args targs = { .x=10, .y=25 };
        
        // Шаг 0 - возвращаем целое число
        int* res_int; // это указатель на целое число. То есть указатель на то место в памяти, где будет лежать результат
        pthread_t pid0;
        pthread_create ( &pid0, NULL, func_int_from_thread, (void*)&targs );
        pthread_join ( pid0, (void**)&res_int );
        int tmp = *res_int;
        printf ( "Integer result: %d \n", tmp );
        // результат возвращается нормально. Отметим следующие особеннсти:
        // 1) выделение памяти происходит внутри "поточной функции" func_int_from_thread
        // 2) возвращается из "поточной функции" всегда указатель
     
        // Шаг 1 - возвращаем float
        // Напишем вторую "поточную функцию", которая возвращает float
        float* res_float; // это указатель на float - число. То есть указатель на то место в памяти, где будет лежать результат
        pthread_t pid1;
        pthread_create ( &pid1, NULL, func_float_from_thread, (void*)&targs );
        pthread_join ( pid1, (void**)&res_float );
        float tmpf = *res_float;
        printf ( "Float result: %f \n", tmpf );

        // Шаг 2 - возвращаем структуру
        struct thread_rez* sres; 
        pthread_t pid2;
        pthread_create ( &pid2, NULL, func_struct_from_thread, (void*)&targs );
        pthread_join ( pid2, (void**)& sres);
        printf ( "Struct result 1: %f \n", sres->rez );
        printf ( "Struct result 2: \n");
        for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
            printf("%d ", sres->arr[i]);

    }
```

Вывод программы:

```
    Integer result: 150
    Float result: 147.399994
    Struct result 1: 120.199997
    Struct result 2:
    1 2 3
```